# Disable writing RAID degraded mode

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a RAID5 with 5 disks on my machine and suspect the motherboard chipset to fail at some points and make my raid going in degraded mode.

Last time it happened I noticed it on the failure of the 2nd drive connected to the same chipset and lost a lot of data. So I would like to prevent this, and especially I would like to have mdadm **disable writes on the raid if one of the disk fails**. So that in between I get notified, I recover and can use my system again. Sadly I could not find it in `man mdadm` so I was wondering if this is possible via a tool or hidden option since for me it looks like a standard feature of a RAID system.

If this is not possible I would also be happy with a solution to stop the raid if degraded.

Answer (score -1):

If you suspect a controller failure: replace the controller. Ignoring the problem won't make it go away.

Comment: I know, it's just for the time I will require to find the root cause (probably coming in a future post ^^), meanwhile I need it working.

Comment: this isn't an answer to the question at all, please attempt to answer what the OP has asked.

Comment: @AlanTuring If someone asks "How can I painlessly shoot myself in the foot" my advice will always be: "do not shoot yourself". I will **NOT** knowingly provide any kind of assistance that may cause disaster for the user. Do **not** try to work around faulty hardware. Period.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers because you of course have a better overview of the user situation than himself and can better than himself judge the different solutions that he has in front of him to choose the correct one... Suppose I need the problem to reproduce itsel to have more information to decide what to replace (I just suspect until now) and I dont want to have to format my RAID5 each time this happen...